# Debugging instal4j installer

Tags: debugging, install4j

I've be struggling in debugging an install4j installer where I'm trying to introduce some complicated condition expression that is failing for some reason.

However when I try to use the debug_installer.sh script I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Applications/install4j/resource/MessagesDefault (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at com.install4j.runtime.util.FileResourceBundle.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.Messages.createMessagesInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.Messages.createMessages(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.Messages.getMessages(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.showMessageInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:199)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:652)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

The file actually doesn't exist but I have no idea of what that file should contain. My install4j version is 4.2.8

Answer (score 1):

In the debug installer start script, replace

```
-cp i4jruntime.jar:user.jar:user/*.jar
```

with

```
-cp 'i4jruntime.jar:user.jar:user/*'
```

Then it should work. This bug was fixed in 5.0.1.

Comment: Currently the classpath is set to -cp i4jruntime.jar:user.jar. I've tried to change it with -cp 'i4jruntime.jar:user.jar:user/*' but I get the same error

Comment: Did you cd to the directory where the debug installer script has been created before executing it? the path /Applications/install4j/resource/MessagesDefault looks strange in teh context of a debug installer

Comment: Yes i'm running it from the directory /Applications/install4j/resource

Comment: You should run it from the directory where the debug installer was created.

Comment: If I do so, the i4jruntime.jar won't be found... any extra modification that need to be done to the script?

Comment: That was the fix in my answer. Do you have i4jruntime.jar in the debug installer directory?

Comment: I don't, but i can see it in the /Applications/install4j/resource folder. However my installer is generated via maven into a separate folder.

Comment: What if you copy that file into the "debug_..." directory?

Comment: I get the same FileNotFoundException